# Analysing a context-free grammar

Tags: computer-science, formal-languages, context-free-grammar

Let:

$$S \to AC \mid BC\\
A \to aAb \mid aA \mid a\\
B \to aBb \mid Bb \mid b\\
C \to Cc \mid c$$

I need to find if:

1. the word $aabbbcc $ is in the grammar, and if so to write a very left series, and the tree.
2. what is the words that generated by grammar?
3. to tell if the grammer is ambiguous

---

**My try:**

1. Yes, $aabbbcc$ is in the grammar because $S\Longrightarrow BC\Longrightarrow aBbC \Longrightarrow aaBbbC\Longrightarrow aabbbC\Longrightarrow aabbbCc \Longrightarrow aabbbcc$

   [image]
2. The laguage is $\mathscr{L}=\{a^ib^jc^*|i\neq j\}$
3. I can't find a word that I can get from two diffrent derivations, so I think that the grammar isn't ambiguous

I'm not sure if my attempt is correct or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right about 1.

In 2, $c^*$ is usually used to mean sequences of zero or more $c$s, but in this grammar there must be at least one $c$.

For 3, as $aa \Longleftarrow aA \Longleftarrow A$ and $aab \Longleftarrow aAb \Longleftarrow A$, $aaab$ can be parsed two ways as an $A$:

$$
aaab \Longleftarrow aAb \Longleftarrow A\\
aaab \Longleftarrow aA \Longleftarrow A.
$$

and so $aabbc$ can be parsed two ways as an $AC$ and so as an $S$.

Comment: about $2$ that should be $c^{+}$?  (+1)

Comment: Yes, $c^+$ is the standard notation for sequences of one or more $c$s.

Comment: About $3$ do you mean: $S\Longrightarrow AC\Longrightarrow aAbc\Longrightarrow aaAbc \Longrightarrow aaabc$ $\color{blue}{\text{and}}$ $S\Longrightarrow AC\Longrightarrow aAc\Longrightarrow aaAbc \Longrightarrow aaabc$?

Comment: Yes. I've updated the answer.